# A call graph of Perl functions in DOT

Tags: perl, graph, doxygen, graphviz, dot

I need to document my Perl program with a function call graph in [.dot](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DOT_language) format.
So, I need a visual representation of function calls flow beginning with some "main" function, that can be acquired automatically.
I know, that I can use [GraphViz2.pm](http://search.cpan.org/~rsavage/GraphViz2-1.11/lib/GraphViz2.pm) and [Doxygen](http://www.doxygen.nl/), but I don't know how.
Thank you.

Comment: Found another [link](http://www.perl.org/about/whitepapers/perl-profiling.html) with [Devel::NYTProf](http://search.cpan.org/~timb/Devel-NYTProf-4.06/), but it's used for profiling, not for static analysis.

Comment: You can't really do static analysis on a dynamic language because you can't tell what the definition behind a sub name will be. NYTProf is a profiler, but it also makes a call graph. With a covered test suite, you should be able to trust the call graph it creates.

Answer (score 2):

Perlmonks.org has [sub_graph.pl](http://www.perlmonks.org/?node_id=25807) as the first google hit, outputs the graph in dot too.

Comment: 'sub graph' not 'subgraph'.  ;)

Comment: Thank you, I'll try it out. Based oun your answer I found another interesting conversation: [Perl subroutine graphing](http://jays.net/wiki/Perl_subroutine_graphing).